# how to use go channel to handle 2 process concurrently

Tags: go, channel

here's 2 method processes as below. firstly get 4 batches list in `method01` in order, start_id of each batch list is the last_id of previous batch. after that, I wanna concurrently run `method02` for each result batch by using go channel, how to write it high availability

```golang
for 0 range 3:{
    list := method01(id, limit)
    id := list[len(list) - 1].getId()
}
// for each above batch list, do method02 concurrently
method02(list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i:=0; i < 3; i++ {
    list := method01(id, limit)
    id := list[len(list) - 1].getId()
    // for each above batch list, do method02 concurrently
    go method02(list)
}
```

`go` keyword is all you need to make the function concurrent. You can learn more at [go tour page](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1). I also would suggest to use something like [sync.WaitGroup](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups) so you can wait for your processes to finish.

Comment: okay let me check, actually inside logic of `method02` I have used `sync.WaitGroup` for handling some concurrently

Comment: I  have added a link to how to use WaitGroup, channels in go usually used for communication now, if your goal is only concurrent synchronization, sync.WaitGroup is more than enough.